# Laravel set route issue for post method

Tags: php, laravel

This is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('/categories/new') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
</form>
```

This is my url where my form is located: /categories/new

This is my route:

```
 Route::get('/categories/new', 'Admin\CategoriesController@newCategory');
```

I want to keep the `new` method, so i want to check if there is a post method do smth else load the view with my form. How can I achieve this in laravel 5. I'm a newbie so all of the detailed explanations are welcomed. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use single method for both `POST` and `GET` requests, you can use [`match` or `any`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing), for example:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', 'someController@someMethod');
```

To detect what request is used:

```
$method = $request->method();

if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#request-path-and-method

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your rotes file:

```
Route::post('/categories/new', 'Admin\CategoriesController@someOtherFunctionHere');
```